# How add Vue syntax highlighting into JSP file

Tags: eclipse, jsp, vue.js

I am using Vue in JSP files. The software is Eclipse STS. But JSP in JSP Editor, Vue syntax is not supported.

I tried Codemix plugin. But no go. Because Codemix supports only vue files, it seems. Any help would be appreciated.

```
<button @click = "frmSubmit()" type="submit" class="btn btn-info pull-right">확인</button>
```

`@click` or `:href="this section should be highlighted,either"`
but they are just treated as string or undefined attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Supporting those as attribute names has simply not been asked for, at least in a JSP. They should be recognized in the upcoming March release with the resolution to https://bugs.eclipse.org/543994 . A plug-in being able to assume responsibility for syntax coloring those attribute's values would take longer, but there's no solution for it yet, nor a feature request to work out how to do it.